# fitting curve to histogram and extracting functional form - Python

Tags: python, function, histogram

If i have plotted a histogram in python using matplotlib, how can i easily extract the functional form of the histogram, or i suppose, the function of the bestfit curve to the histogram. Im not sure how to plot this bestfit curve. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

The shape of my histogram is like an inverted lennard-jones potential.

Comment: That's not really a Python-specific or even a programming question. You might be better off asking for an algorithm in [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Do you want to know about how to the fit or how to plot the result or both?

Comment: oh right. wow. im quite the newb so i thought there might be a matplotlib command that would plot the bestfit. thanks anyway!

Comment: I suppose a better question is actually how to plot a best fit curve to a data set, in this case a histogram!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just going to answer both to be thorough. These are two separate problems: fitting a function to your histogram data and then plotting the function. First of all, scipy has an [optimization module](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html) that you can use to fit your function. Among those [curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) is probably the easiest.

To give an example,

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Model function
def f(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b

# Example data
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 20)
y = f(x, 0.2, 3.4) + 0.2 * np.random.normal(size=len(x))

# Do the fit
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y, [1.0, 1.0])
```

From `curve_fit` you get the optimized parameters `a, b` to your function `f` and the statistical covariances. You can also pass error for statistical weights as `sigma` to it.

Now you can plot the data and the histogram. I guess it makes sense to use a higher resolution in `x` for the curve.

```
# Plot data
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')

# Plot fit curve
fit_x = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)
plt.plot(fit_x, f(fit_x, *popt))
plt.show()
```

I haven't specifically dealt with a histogram nor a Lennard-Jones potential here to limit the complexity of the code and focus on the part you asked about. But this example can be adapted to any kind of least squares optimization issue.

Comment: Thankyou aepsil0n for your thorough reply. While i have your help on hand, could i ask you how i could adapt my histogram to the inputs x and y. As i currently have it, my histogram is merely defined by n, bins, patches = plt.hist(Vvec, num_bins, normed=1, facecolor='red',edgecolor = "none", alpha=0.5) ....where Vvec is my x-axis input, how can i extract my x and y from this definition?

Comment: You're welcome. This is actually something I stumbled upon quite a few times since switching from gnuplot to Python for interactive data analysis, so I thought it would be worth writing down for once. Wait a sec...

Comment: Ok, so basically y -> n, and x -> bins. It is not quite as simple though, since bins is 1 element bigger than n. So you have to extract the relevant data, which may be the left side of the bin (`bins[:-1]`), the right side (`bins[1:]`), the center (`(bins[:-1]+bins[1:])/2`) or something else. Depends how you want to model it.

Comment: Brilliant, thats all i needed to know, got it working. Thankyou again!